# how to handle filtered list click listner on class exending baseadapter?

Tags: android, xml, baseadapter, listadapter

every one! I am a new bie in android...In my app after clicking the button on fragment I switch to new  Activity which shows the list then I filtered the list and now I want to get details of selected filtered list item back to calling fragment...I tried for onClick Listener in the getView method of adapter class which extends base adapter but it not switch to calling fragment..it remains there only

```
My Adapter classs

public class user_list_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public static ArrayList<user_list_item> user_arraylist;
    private ArrayList<user_list_item> arraylist;
    public static String selected_code;

    public user_list_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<user_list_item> user_array) {
        this.context = context;
        this.user_arraylist = user_array;
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<user_list_item>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(user_array);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return user_arraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return user_arraylist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_row, null);
        }

        TextView txtname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dname);
        TextView txtcode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dcode);

        txtname.setText(user_arraylist.get(position).getCust_name());
        txtcode.setText(user_arraylist.get(position).getCode());

        // Listen for ListView Item Click
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
              Deposite df = new Deposite();
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context; //this line gives class cast exception
            FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("search_name ", search_name);
            b.putString("search_code ", search_code);
            df.setArguments(b);
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, df);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
                    }
        });

        return convertView;
    }


    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        user_arraylist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            user_arraylist.addAll(arraylist);
        }
        else
        {
            for (user_list_item item : arraylist)
            {
                if (item.getCust_name().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
                {
                    user_arraylist.add(item);
                }

                if (item.getCode().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
                {
                    user_arraylist.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Adpater class with inner class filter

```
public class user_list_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<user_list_item> implements Filterable 
{

    private Filter mfilter;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<user_list_item> filter_user_list;
    private ArrayList<user_list_item> alluserlist;
    //public static String selected_code;

    public user_list_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<user_list_item> user_array) {
        super(context,R.layout.user_row,user_array);
        this.context = context;
        this.filter_user_list = user_array;
        this.alluserlist = new ArrayList<user_list_item>();
        this.alluserlist.addAll(user_array);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return filter_user_list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public user_list_item getItem(int position) {

        return filter_user_list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

       return filter_user_list.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    public void resetData() {
        filter_user_list = alluserlist;
    }


    /* *********************************
     * We use the holder pattern
     * It makes the view faster and avoid finding the component
     * **********************************/

    private static class UserHolder {
        public TextView txtname;
        public TextView txtcode;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        UserHolder uholder=new UserHolder();

        // First let's verify the convertView is not null
        if (convertView == null) {
            // This a new view we inflate the new layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_row, null);
            // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
            TextView tvname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dname);
            TextView tvcode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dcode);


            uholder.txtname = tvname;
            uholder.txtcode = tvcode;

            convertView.setTag(uholder);
        }
        else
            uholder = (UserHolder) convertView.getTag();

        user_list_item p = filter_user_list.get(position);
        uholder.txtname.setText(p.getCust_name());
        uholder.txtcode.setText(p.getCode());

        return convertView;
    }

        /*
     * We create our filter
     */

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mfilter == null)
            mfilter = new userFilter();

        return mfilter;
    }

    private class userFilter extends Filter {

       @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charText) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // We implement here the filter logic
            if (charText == null || charText.length() == 0) {
                // No filter implemented we return all the list
                results.values = alluserlist;
                results.count = alluserlist.size();
            }
            else {
                // We perform filtering operation
                List<user_list_item> uList = new ArrayList<user_list_item>();

                for (user_list_item p : filter_user_list) {
                    if (p.getCust_name().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    uList.add(p);
                }

                    if (p.getCode().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    uList.add(p);
                }
                }

                results.values = uList;
                results.count = uList.size();

            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {

            // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
            if (results.count == 0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else {

                filter_user_list = (ArrayList<user_list_item>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    }

    }
```

In My search_window Activity class ie.List class which calls adapter class
set onItemclick listener as

```
 // Binds the Adapter to the ListView

 list.setAdapter(adapter);

       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {

                // We know that each row in the adapter is a Map
                user_list_item row =  adapter.getItem(position);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You Clicked On.."+row.getCust_name(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MainActivity.deposite_search_flag = true;     //global static variable 
                MainActivity.search_name = row.getCust_name(); //global 
                MainActivity.search_code =row.getCode();     //global 
                for (int i=0;i<RecordList.size();i++){  //user_list_item only contains name n code
                    if (row.getCode()==Code_Array[i]){
                        MainActivity.search_available = avail_bal_Array[i];
                    }
                }
                finish();  //switch to caller fragment and executes OnResume method of fragment
            }
        });
```

by setting global variables on MainActivity class I switched to caller fragment by directly finishing this activity(finish();)

```
//In caller fragment class
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (MainActivity.deposite_search_flag){
            txtname.setText(MainActivity.search_name);
            txtcode.setText(MainActivity.search_code);
            txt_available_bal.setText(MainActivity.search_available);
        }
    }
```